# how to make std::functions and lambdas which could take any type of argument

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, std-function

I have simplified this as much as I can and hopefully, it will be clear.
I have a class called Foo which contains an std::function member that is bind to a function that I want to call.

When `Foo::DoCallback` is called, the function that is a bind or assigned is executed. In order to support the different types of parameters, I have created 2 constructors and a default constructor that takes no parameter

a constructor that takes std::function with an int type parameter.

`Foo(std::function<void(int)> callback, int a)`

a constructor that takes std::function that takes a bool parameter.

`Foo(std::function<void(bool)> callback, bool condition)`

and the default constructor that takes no parameters at all.

`Foo(std::function<void()> callback = nullptr) : Callback(callback)`

in the main, I have 3 lambdas.
each lambda takes a different type of parameters and passes them as an argument to the function that would be used as a callback.

```
  auto lambdaA = [](int a)
  {
    FunctionA(a);
  };

  auto lambdaB = [](bool condition)
  {
    FunctionB(condition);
  };

  auto lambdaC = []()
  {
    FunctionC();
  };
```

The problem is that, whenever I need a new callback with different types of argument, I have to keep creating;

- a lambda that needs to be passed as an argument when creating the Foo unique ptr.
- a foo constructor that takes the new type of std::function parameter that takes the additional types of parameter.

Is there a way to make this simpler?

here is the full code

--main--

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "Foo.h"
void FunctionA(int a)
{
  std::cout << "FunctionA called. param 1 = " << std::to_string(a) << "\n";
}

void FunctionB(bool condition)
{
  std::cout << "FunctionB called. param 1 = " << std::to_string(condition) << "\n";
}

void FunctionC()
{
  std::cout << "FunctionC called with no params" << "\n";
}
int main()
{
  auto lambdaA = [](int a)
  {
    FunctionA(a);
  };

  auto lambdaB = [](bool condition)
  {
    FunctionB(condition);
  };

  auto lambdaC = []()
  {
    FunctionC();
  };

  std::unique_ptr<Foo> FooPtrA = std::make_unique<Foo>(lambdaA,10);
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> FooPtrB = std::make_unique<Foo>(lambdaB ,false);
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> FooPtrC = std::make_unique<Foo>(lambdaC);

  FooPtrA->DoCallback();
  FooPtrB->DoCallback();
  FooPtrC->DoCallback();

  return 0;
}
```

-- Foo.h

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
class Foo
{
public:
  //constructor with a parameter callback which could take an int parameter
  Foo(std::function<void(int)> callback, int a) 
  {
    Callback = std::bind(callback, a);
  }
  //constructor with a parameter callback which could take a bool parameter
  Foo(std::function<void(bool)> callback, bool condition)
  {
    Callback = std::bind(callback, condition);
  }

  //constructor with a parameter callback which takes no parameter
  Foo(std::function<void()> callback = nullptr) : Callback(callback)
  {
  }

  void DoCallback()
  {
    Callback(); //calling the callback function that is binded
  }
private:
  std::function<void()> Callback;
};
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: Your example doesn't use `lambdaA`, `lambdaB`, or `lambdaC` at all.

Comment: yea typo on my hand.

Comment: Why not just `auto lambdaA = FunctionA;`?

Comment: @Eric ooo! didn't know i could do that! the original code within the lambda scope has other things other than function assignment though.

Comment: If the lambda does more than just call the inner function, then it sounds like you need to write a new one on a case-by-case basis anyway.

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't your `Foo` simply a `std::function<void()>`?

Comment: @appleapple Or maybe even just another name for `std::bind`

Comment: @apple apple, i have simplified this so it doesn't take much space. the original code is not even foo. its called DelayTimer. it takes a delay value in milliseconds. waits till the delay time is complete and then calls the callback function that is binded

Comment: @Nusakan well, what `/*something*/ SetTimeout(std::function<void> callback, float delay)` cannot do for you? No need to bind inside function/class at all.

Comment: @Eric yeah, it's more like `std::bind`. (when I start use `function`, I've had lambda, so it does not come to my mind when I reply :P)

Comment: I see what you mean but that means I have to change all the code where this "foo" is used. the original code is written by another programmer who done the code long ago. it makes perfect sense to do that though. unless if im missing some details from his code due to my ignorance.

Comment: @Nusakan: Just use the single-argument `Foo::Foo(f)` constructor in your code then, and call it as `Foo(std::bind(f, a, b, c, ...))` - then you don't need any of those constructors in `Foo` at all.

Comment: @Eric ooo!.. why couldn't think of that! thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going one stage further than Swordfish's answer, you can eliminate the overhead of an `std::function` by parametrizing with any type:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
Foo(F f, T a)
    : Callback{ std::bind(f, a) } } {}
```

If you want this to work for arbitrary numbers of arguments, and call move constructors correctly:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
Foo(F&& f, Args&&... a)
    : Callback{ std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(a)...) } {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a template?

```
template<typename T>
Foo(std::function<void(T)> callback, T a) : Callback{ std::bind(callback, a); }
{}
```